# Deleting tables with regular expressions

Tags: regex, vim, text

Not really a specific question, since I don't know enough - more of a question on how to approach this.

Example file can be seen below:

```
 LOADING CONDITION :   4-Homogenous cargo 98% 1.018t/m3, draught 3.35m   
                       - outgoing               


                               ITEMS OF LOADING        
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CAPA  ITEM REFERENCE    X1      X2     WEIGHT    KG     LCG      YG       FSM  
  No                     (m)     (m)      (t)     (m)    (m)      (m)     (t.m) 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  13 No2 CARGO TK P      1.650  29.400   609.04  2.745  15.525  -3.384    483.49
  14 No2 CARGO TK S      1.650  29.400   603.61  2.745  15.525   3.384    483.49
  15 No1 CARGO TK P     29.400  56.400   587.23  2.745  42.900  -3.384    470.42
  16 No1 CARGO TK S     29.400  56.400   592.45  2.745  42.900   3.384    470.42
  17 MGO tank aft       21.150  23.400    23.42  6.531  22.275  -0.500     15.70
  18 TO storage tank    21.150  23.400     2.68  7.225  22.275   2.300      0.00
  19 MGO fore tank      33.150  35.400    25.90  6.643  34.275  -0.212      0.00
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 DEADWEIGHT                             2444.34  2.828  29.007  -0.005   1923.52


                               SUMMARY OF LOADING      

                                        WEIGHT    KG     LCG      YG       FSM  
                                          (t)     (m)    (m)      (m)     (t.m) 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        DEADWEIGHT                      2444.34  2.828  29.007  -0.005   1923.52
        LIGHT SHIP                       634.00  3.030  28.654   0.000      0.00
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        TOTAL WEIGHT                    3078.34  2.869  28.935  -0.004   1923.52





 LOADING CONDITION :   4-Homogenous cargo 98% 1.018t/m3, draught 3.35m   
                       - outgoing               
 Damage Case         : 1bott: all cargo & void3                          
 Flooding Percentage : 100 %
 Flooded Volumes     :   No.3 Void space P  No.3 Void space S  No2 CARGO TK P   
                         No2 CARGO TK S     No1 CARGO TK P     No1 CARGO TK S   


 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            WEIGHT     KG      LCG      YG       FSM     CORR.KG
                              (t)      (m)     (m)      (m)     (t.m)       (m) 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TOTAL WEIGHT               3078.34   2.869   28.935   -0.004    1923.52   3.494
 RUN-OFF WEIGHTS               0.00   0.000    0.000    0.000       0.00   0.000
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 DAMAGE CONDITION           3078.34   2.869   28.935   -0.004    1923.52   3.494




 EQUILIBRIUM NOT FOUND ON STARBOARD                                             






 LOADING CASE :                                                                 
      4-Homogenous cargo 98% 1.018t/m3, draught 3.35m - outgoing                


 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            WEIGHT     KG      LCG      YG       FSM     CORR.KG
                              (t)      (m)     (m)      (m)     (t.m)       (m) 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TOTAL WEIGHT               3078.34   2.869   28.935   -0.004    1923.52   3.494


                    SUMMARY OF RESULTS OF DAMAGE STABILITY                      
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       DAMAGE CASE               %  R  HEEL   GM     FBmin   GZ>0  GZmax  Area  
                                      (deg)   (m)     (m)   (deg)   (m)  (m.rad)
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1bott: all cargo & void3       100 0 EQUILIBRIUM NOT FOUND                     


 %     : Flooding percentage.                                                   
 R     : R=1 if run-off weights considered, R=0 if no run-off.                  
 HEEL  : Heel at equilibrium (negative if equilibrium is on port).              
 GM    : GM at equilibrium.                                                     
 FBmin : Minimum distance of margin line, weathertight or non-weathertight      
         points from waterline.                                                 
 GZ>0  : Range of positive GZ limited to immersion of non-weathertight openings.
 GZmax : Maximum GZ value.
```

It is one of many, they can differ a bit, but they all come down to tables in textual form. I need to clean up some items from them, before pasting them in a report.

So I was wondering - what would be the text way to delete a certain table. For example, *SUMMARY OF LOADING* (it starts with the line containing "SUMMARY OF LOADING" and end in the line containing "TOTAL WEIGHT").

How to match that table and delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following from within vim

```
:g/SUMMARY OF LOADING/, /TOTAL WEIGHT/d
```

sed works in the same way:

```
sed '/SUMMARY OF LOADING/, /TOTAL WEIGHT/d' input_with_tables.txt
```

Comment: It starts with "SUMMARY OF LOADING" okey, then the ", " part then ... where it ends. What is the ", " part? Could you explain just a bit?

Comment: the `,` defines a range (inclusive) defined by the start-regex and the end-regex. The command `d` operates on this range, in this case it's delete. Read more @ http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges

Comment: So generally, it makes a range from (and including) the line SUMMARY up to and including the line TOTAL, and then deletes them all, linewise?

Answer (score 0):

Fredrik Pihl's solution with `:g` works well if you need to delete *all* such tables. For more specific edits, you could use my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) to create custom motions and text objects by defining start and end patterns (like `SUMMARY OF LOADING` and `TOTAL WEIGHT` in your case), and then quickly jump to the next table and delete a table with a quick mapping.